# How can I Authenticate by username and pass in MailKit?

Tags: mailkit, mimekit

I am using Mailkit to send mails in my asp.net core 3.1 application.
I can connect and authenticate using my google account. But when I moved to use my business account, I can not authenticate using starttls option with the following code:

```
                client.CheckCertificateRevocation = false;
                client.Connect(  Host,25, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
                client.Authenticate(new NetworkCredential(Username, Password));
```

The result is "535: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful".
However, I can connect using .net smtpclient using this code:

```
                var smtpclient= new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =ValidateServerCertificate
                smtpclient.Host = Host;
                smtpclient.Port = 25;
                smtpclient.EnableSsl = true;
                var cred= new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                cred.UserName =Username;
                cred.Password = Password;
                smtpclient.Credentials = cred;
                smtpclient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                smtpclient.Send(message);
```

- If I removed the domain name from my username, I can authenticate but not starttls mode.
- I can connect anonymous using starttls.

So how can I solve  this issue?
This is sample of my log:

```
Connected to smtp://ip:25/?starttls=always
S: 220 xxxxxxx Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at dt

C: EHLO [ip]

S: 250-xxxx Hello [ip]

S: 250-SIZE 104857600

S: 250-PIPELINING

S: 250-DSN

S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

S: 250-STARTTLS

S: 250-X-ANONYMOUSTLS

S: 250-AUTH NTLM LOGIN

S: 250-X-EXPS GSSAPI NTLM

S: 250-8BITMIME

S: 250-BINARYMIME

S: 250-CHUNKING

S: 250 XRDST
```

Comment: Edit your question. Show the code you are using, remove the code you are not using. Show the error message. Provide details on what you are connecting to (O365, Exchange, etc). Your question mentions Google. Google authorization is different than Microsoft's. The Google part has no relevance.

Comment: the code in my post is the code that I am using . I can not authenticate using credentials, however I can anonymously authenticate.  I do not know if this issue from Mailkit or smtp server doesn't support authentication? and why .net smtpclient authenticate using the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

MailKit 2.x's (including 2.15) implementation of NTLM authentication is known to not work correctly in all conditions.

You can try doing this to make sure that MailKit doesn't use NTLM:

```
client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove ("NTLM");
client.Authenticate (username, password);
```

Or you can actively force a particular authentication mechanism like this:

```
client.Authenticate (new SaslMechanismLogin (username, password));
```

If that doesn't work, it's probably because either your username/password are wrong or else the server is just configured to reject LOGIN authentication.

An upcoming MailKit v3.0 release has a working NTLM implementation that afaict works in all cases.